# How to understand a session on an sql server?

Tags: mysql, session

Hi am confused with sql servers session. What does it actually mean? Does it keep track of the client like httpSession? I have read some documents on query life cycle. None talks about the sesion. Most of the documents say that after the query is recived by the server it gets parsed and then maintains a syntax tree and then execution plan and then executes the query and then a dispatch palan and then dispatches the resultset to the client who issued the query on the server. In the whole story where does the session on sql server like mysql server fits in and what actually it does? or There is no session concept on Mysql server(any sql server)? am i in wrong imagination?

Comment: Question is tagged as MySQL but you mention Microsoft SQL Server all the time. Are you asking about differences between both DBMS?

Comment: I don't mean microsoft sql server. I meant to say a server that simply implements sql. This is what i meant when i said sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *session* in this context usually just refers to a single client connection.

The client connects to the DB server and authenticates; this is the start of the session.
When the client disconnects (gracefully or not) the session ends.

This is relevant for things like temporary tables or transactions: Un-committed transactions will be rolled back by the DBMS and all *temporary* tables created through this connection (=session) are discarded when the client disconnects, i.e. when the session ends.

Note that a client does not necessarily actively end a session or connection. The client may crash, or the network connection may break, or the server may shut down &c. Any of this implicitly terminates the session.

Problems may arise when a (client) application uses a connection pool keeping connections (and sessions) open and handing them out transparently to different application components. When not handled correctly, errors may occur because a given session may already be 'spoiled' by a previous operation. If, for example, one routine on the client creates a temporary table named 'X' and fails to explicitly drop it afterwards, the next routine that 'inherits' this session may encounter an error when trying to create another temporary table of that name, because it already exists in this specific session; which couldn't be the case if the connection/session was freshly created.

Answer (score 1):

"Session" is mainly a generic term. You connect to a server (MySQL, Oracle, FTP, IRC... whatever), you do your stuff and finally disconnect when you're done. That has been a session.

*HTTP is a particular case. It's a stateless protocol: if you spend an hour reading a web site, you don't remain connected for a whole hour. You make a quick connection, fetch an item at a time (an HTML document, a style sheet, a picture...) and close the connection. (Internals are actually more complex but that's the general idea.) When you ask for a second page, the server doesn't know who you are: that makes it impossible to keep track of your whole browsing session at protocol level. Thus HTTP sessions were invented: they're a way to emulate physical sessions.*

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL session starts when you open a connection to the server. A connection ID is assigned which can be read via the `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()` statement. The session is terminated when the connection is closed or, in case of persistent connections, after a certain timeout or when the server shuts down.